# Scrolling through hidden content in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, input, overflow

I found really weird bug in Chrome  and I need your help. I have div with `overflow: hidden` and input inside of it. When I click and drag-select text in this input, moving mouse down like if I wanted to select few lines, that forces scrolling through hidden content.

Try this out in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bwgan/

Has someone met this problem? How can I fix it with css only?

Comment: Please include your code in your question.  What happens when the jsfiddle link breaks?  This question becomes useless to future visitors with the same problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue.. Are you sure this fiddle is correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
input:active { pointer-events:none; }
```

in your css. It will work.

Comment: Yes... I have also faced this issue once. So knew about this solution :)

Comment: Unfortunately this also prevents the user from scrolling down with the mouse.  See my solution for a more robust approach.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post about my findings in this area here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kurlak/archive/2013/11/03/hiding-vertical-scrollbars-with-pure-css-in-chrome-ie-8-firefox-opera-and-safari.aspx

In summary, you basically do this: http://jsfiddle.net/d4D8M/

```
.element, .outer-container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.outer-container {
    border: 5px solid purple;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-container {
    position: absolute;
        left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.inner-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

and:

```
<div class="outer-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="element">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vehicula quam nibh, eu tristique tellus dignissim quis. Integer condimentum ultrices elit ut mattis. Praesent rhoncus tortor metus, nec pellentesque enim mattis nec. Nulla vitae turpis ut dui consectetur pellentesque quis vel est. Curabitur rutrum, mauris ut mollis lobortis, sem est congue lectus, ut sodales nunc leo a libero. Cras quis sapien in mi fringilla tempus condimentum quis velit. Aliquam id aliquam arcu. Morbi tristique aliquam rutrum. Duis tincidunt, orci suscipit cursus molestie, purus nisi pharetra dui, tempor dignissim felis turpis in mi. Vivamus ullamcorper arcu sit amet mauris egestas egestas. Vestibulum turpis neque, condimentum a tincidunt quis, molestie vel justo. Sed molestie nunc dapibus arcu feugiat, ut sollicitudin metus sagittis. Aliquam a volutpat sem. Quisque id magna ultrices, lobortis dui eget, pretium libero. Curabitur aliquam in ante eu ultricies.

Quisque vitae tincidunt purus. Vivamus feugiat bibendum erat, nec interdum urna porta sed. Nunc lobortis neque orci, ut suscipit nisl congue feugiat. Vivamus feugiat tellus quis cursus sollicitudin. Curabitur dolor massa, dictum ut ipsum in, porttitor pellentesque ante. Aenean egestas cursus tempor. Maecenas semper tortor sit amet egestas cursus. Mauris porttitor quis nisi ut tincidunt. Curabitur adipiscing eleifend nibh. Praesent mauris leo, consequat vitae orci eget, vestibulum bibendum nisi. Aliquam tempus diam ut tortor cursus, eget sodales augue adipiscing. Nulla at dignissim libero.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```